# Opening a new window with javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window or tab pointing to a different url taken from a link by using javascript. This is the code:

```
<script>
        window.open($('#my_a_link_id').get(0).href);
</script>
```

However, nothing happens. What I am missing here? I have checked already that the `$('#my_a_link_id').get(0).href` expression has the correct value.

Comment: Check for browser permissions to open new windows.

Comment: Imagine this: A bad individual puts on each page, the `window.open` opens, a script opening a new window. And in each new window he also calls `alert()`. You get the idea, it would open the doors for lots of security risks.

Comment: Yes, I see the point. It's a pity we have to pay for all those jerks out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser won't let you open a window on your own, it's a feature in browsers since the early 2000s called "popup blockers".

If you must open a window, you have to do it as part of user interaction (user clicked the mouse or navigated to a link with the keyboard and interacted with it in that way, etc).

It's worth noting that opening new windows is considered bad UI and is generally not recommended. There's almost always a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in a new tab, you have to use the keyword `target` on a `a` tag :

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/" target="_blank">My Website</a>
```

You can do it dynamically with js.

It will open a new tab (default) or a new window depending how the user configured his browser.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying that way but it didn't work neither.